# Scoping filter for user provisioning based on appRole membership. Error 'SchemaInvalid'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, scim, microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-private-access

in Azure during SCIM configuration we are able to select **Source Object Scope** and add Scoping Filter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/define-conditional-rules-for-provisioning-user-accounts?pivots=app-provisioning#scoping-filter-construction).

I want to add filter which will check users appRoleAssignment and verify if user is assigned to ACCOUNT role, something like below:
[SCIM scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKyAr.png)
appRoleAssignment is available in scoping selection but when I try to save changes I got error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xevct.png)

How to solve it ? Is there any way to create that kind of scoping filer?

Thanks in advance